# How to get assembly codes which access memory section in other process ? - C#

Tags: c#, assembly

I mean how can i make function like "Find out what accesses this address" in Cheat engine.

I need a quick good Function

and thanks

Comment: If you have a source, then you can use Intellisense to find all references to a variable. But if you want to `attach to a running process` and `debug` it, then your question suddenly is not anymore *quick* or *function*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IDebugControl::AddBreakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537856.aspx).